# Month names variants

Tags: list-of-languages, cases

Regarding the question on [TeX.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328272/change-the-case-of-datetime2-month-return) I am looking for generally used languages that use different cases for their month and day names.

Based on Czech and Slovak languages I can imagine two cases useful for automatic typesetting of such names:

- Nominative case: report for *January* 2016 - zpráva za *Leden* 2016;
- Genitive case: *January* 5th, 2016 - 5. *Ledna*, 2016.
- Locative case: report written in *January* - zpráva napsaná v *Lednu*

Other cases (14 in total with plural forms) doesn't seem useful for automated typesetting.

Reasoning for this question is: Is it worth embedding this "case sensitivity" to the core package or change in language variants will be sufficient?

Comment: Can you please clarify the terminology? The term of "case sensitivity" has an established meaning in IT of upper/lower cases. The same is "typesetting", it's about the layout in printing industry. Also, if the question is about the noun cases, "worth" and "usefulness" depend on the purpose of the software you're developing. I can think of phrases where the month/weekday name are in Dative (*"complete by January"*) or Instrumental (*"period starts on Monday"*). Also, most accounting/banking software I saw here in Ukraine are able to produce all noun cases for month/weekday names.

Comment: "Typesetting" refers to LaTeX processor. I also know about "case sensitivity" in IT, but I didn't find proper word for nominative *case*. Accounting and banking software is usually proprietray, closed and localised; LaTeX is open, freeware and localisation is done by aditional packages. SW dedicated for UK doesn't need to bother with names, but  Ukrainian does.

Comment: "Lednu" is the locative case; the instrumental is "lednem". Aren't both used in Czech? For what it's worth, in Polish we use both the locative and the instrumental: "raport napisany w styczniu" (a report written in January), "raport napisany przed styczniem" (a report written before January).

Comment: UK English (especially when spoken) has *the fifth of January*, which seems to fit your Czech/Slovak genitive

Comment: Speaking of case sensitivity, Czech doesn't capitalise month names.